# Any good Ruby on Rails Ajax scaffold generator for Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

Is there any good Ruby on Rails Ajax scaffold generator for Ruby on Rails 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Active Scaffold](http://activescaffold.com/) seems [stagnant](https://code.google.com/p/activescaffold/issues/detail?id=763&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary) but there is a [fork](https://github.com/vhochstein/active_scaffold#readme) with Rails 3 support.